# TCL - Return Dictionaries within procedures

Tags: tcl

I want to create several procedures to deal with dictionaries, such as:

-> push

-> pop

-> print

etc

I created a procedure that "creates/sets values to a dictionary".

From the point of the user, they would do:

`push myDict1 key value`

`push myDict2 key value`

This would create two different dictionaries with a given key and value.

Now, I would like the procedure to return the dictionary's variable, so the user could do:

`puts $myDict1 or puts $myDict2` and the content would be displayed.

If I do something like:

```
proc push {dictName key value } {
    return [dict set $dictName $key $value]
}
```

it will return the value of the expression, but I want it to write to some sort of global variable, which has the name myDict1 or myDict2, which was specified by the user when calling the procedure.

I have tried using both "variable" and "upvar" with no success.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Cheers,

Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning to use `upvar` can be tricky, you might have used it incorrectly.

```
proc push {dictName key value} { 
    upvar $dictName local_dict

    # Any change to 'local_dict' will affect the $dictName variable 
    #  in the scope that called the proc.
    dict set local_dict $key $value

    return $local_dict
}

set myDict1 [dict create]
push myDict1 key1 value1
puts $myDict1 --> 'key1 value1'
```

(removed an incorrect comment from my original answer)

Comment: "This proc won't work if the myDict variable doesn't already exist though!" Yes it will. `unset mydict; push mydict foo bar` creates "mydict"

Comment: `dict set` will happily make the variable (and has always functioned this way) but the official docs appear to be a bit unclear on this fact. Sorry. My fault.

Comment: Yes, you're right!   I had an unrelated typo that was causing an error that I thought needed to be fixed by `uplevel`.   That seemed strange at the time.   I'll go edit my answer now.

Comment: Thanks all for this.
@ChrisHeithoff This solution is very elegant and, you are right, I was using upvar wrongly.
I thought, as well, that if a list/array/dict don't exist and we do "set" to write to it, it would be created automatically.
So, I think the line with "set myDict1 [dict create]" can be removed.